# Detect which UIImage is tapped inside a uiscrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview, uiimage

I have a `UIScrollView` that is loaded with several `UIImages`, for this example it is loaded with the same picture in 5 `UIImages`. How can I detect which one of the `UIImages` the user tap's ?

This is what i am using :

```
    _thumbnailScroll.delegate = self;

    [_thumbnailScroll setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [_thumbnailScroll setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];

    _thumbnailScroll.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
    _thumbnailScroll.clipsToBounds = NO;
    _thumbnailScroll.scrollEnabled = YES;
    _thumbnailScroll.pagingEnabled = YES;

    NSUInteger nimages = 0;
    NSInteger tot=0;
    CGFloat cx = 0;
    for (nimages = 0; nimages < 5 ; nimages++) {

        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"newPics/thumb/thumb1.png" ]];
        if (tot==5) {
            break;
        }
        if (5==nimages) {
            nimages=0;
        }

        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

        CGRect rect = imageView.frame;
        rect.size.height = 150;
        rect.size.width = 150;
        rect.origin.x = cx;
        rect.origin.y = 0;

        imageView.frame = rect;


        [_thumbnailScroll addSubview:imageView];
        _thumbnailScroll.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        // [imageView release];

        cx += imageView.frame.size.width+100;
        tot++;
    }

    //self.pageControl.numberOfPages = nimages;
    [_thumbnailScroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(cx, [_thumbnailScroll bounds].size.height)];
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this for tap listener inside loop.

```
 UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self    action:@selector(onSingleTapGestureRecognized:)];
 singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
 singleTap.delegate = self;
 [imageview1 addGestureRecogniser:singleTap];
 [singleTap1 release];

  imageview1.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

and

action method given by MANIAK_dobrii.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-hitTest:withEvent:` to get the view you need, for example, if you add UITapGestureRecognizer to your _thumbnailScroll you can do it like this:

```
// Add gesture recognizer to a superview of imageviews (i.e. _thumbnailScroll)
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTapGR = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self    action:@selector(onSingleTapGestureRecognized:)];
[_thumbnailScroll addGestureRecogniser:singleTapGR];
...
// Implement it on your controller (who self was above)
- (void)onSingleTapGestureRecognized:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)singleTapGestureRecognizer
{
    UIView *tappedView = [_thumbnailScroll hitTest:[singleTapGestureRecognizer locationInView: _thumbnailScroll] withEvent:nil];

    // check if tappedView is one of your UIImageViews.
    // tapped view will be one of your _thumbnailScroll subviews or itself
    // so you use just use this information later
}
```

Adding a gesture recogniser to each UIImageView is redundant if you only need to know which one was tapped.

Comment: didn't mentioned how to add, gesture recognizer with image. not properly explained.

Comment: @sheshnath what do you mean? I've just expanded my initial answer and it's quite clear. I'm considering your behaviour as offensive and non-constructive.

Answer (score 0):

there are several ways to do that 
. one of the way is to add UITapGestureRecognizer on every UIImageView. set a selector for UITapGestureRecognizer like

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageTapped:)];

[imageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];

and in imageTapped: mathod

-(void)imageTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer{
    UIImageView *imgView=(UIImageView*)[recognizer view];   

}
```

Don't forget to enable the user interaction for UIImageView. because it is disable by default